# not getting expected ambiguity on template specialization and overloading c++

Tags: c++, overloading, template-specialization

Consider

```
Class Wow{
    public:
        //main metod
        template<typename T>
        void foo(T t){
            cout << t << endl;
        }

        template<>
        void foo<int>(int t){
            cout << "specialization" << endl;
        }

        void foo(int t){
            cout << "overloading" << endl;
        }
}
```

and the main is

```
Wow wow;
wow.foo(2.2);
wow.foo(1);
```

this outputs

```
2.2
overloading
```

My question is why does that even compile?
practically, `foo` is defined twice as `void foo(int)`.

1) why does this pass?

2) why does the compiler choose the overloading one?

Thanks

Comment: An overload is always considered a better match than a template instance. Even if the template instance is an explicit specialization. If I had a handy copy of the standard I'd quote it.

Comment: that answers 2). but why does it let the ambiguity pass?

Comment: Because if one is a better match, there is no ambiguity. Ambiguity is when the compiler has no rule by which it can decide to call one or the other.

Comment: The quote @StoryTeller is looking for is `[over.match.best]/1.6`: "[F1 is better than F2 if] F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization"

Comment: One important thing to know: template specializations do not participate in overload resolution. Only after specific overload is selected, compiler checks if there specialization avaliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because there is no problem here. There is template function, function template specialization and overloading. You can call template specialization like this:

```
wow.foo<int>(3);
```

2) Overload has better match, than template specialization, if compiler can call this function with arg.

n4926 13.3.3/1.7

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments
>   i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2) , and
>   then
>
> F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function
>   template specialization